# Error 2 when building CUDA/C++ test program with QtCreator

Tags: c++, cuda, mingw

I got some trouble trying to run a simple test program to start learning CUDA.
I'm trying to have a standard C++ main file calling a kernel function in another file.

The compilation step seems to perform fine but it looks like the linker doesn't know how to deal with the .o files and how to create the .exe
I've tried some modification/options from here: https://devblogs.nvidia.com/separate-compilation-linking-cuda-device-code/

I'm trying to use mingw for the link after compilation. Do I miss some extra library? All the .o files are created correctly in the right places.

But I still can't make my program run.

Here's the error log:

```
19:00:03: Exécution des étapes pour le projet test01...
19:00:03: Configuration inchangée, étape qmake sautée.
19:00:03: Débute : "C:\Qt\Qt5.10.0\Tools\mingw530_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" 
C:\Qt\Qt5.10.0\5.10.0\mingw53_32\bin\qmake.exe -o Makefile ..\test01\test01.pro -spec win32-g++ "CONFIG+=debug" "CONFIG+=qml_debug"
C:/Qt/Qt5.10.0/Tools/mingw530_32/bin/mingw32-make -f Makefile.Debug
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'D:/lab_stuff/programmation/C++/test01/build-test01-Desktop_Qt_5_10_0_MinGW_32bit-Debug'
mingw32_make.exe -Wl,-subsystem,console -mthreads -o debug\test01.exe debug/cuda/vectoradd_cuda.o debug/obj/main.o  -L"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.1\lib\x64" -lcuda -lcudart -lcudadevrt -LC:\Qt\Qt5.10.0\5.10.0\mingw53_32\lib C:\Qt\Qt5.10.0\5.10.0\mingw53_32\lib\libQt5Cored.a 
Makefile.Debug:64: recipe for target 'debug\test01.exe' failed
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'D:/lab_stuff/programmation/C++/test01/build-test01-Desktop_Qt_5_10_0_MinGW_32bit-Debug'
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, mingw32_make.exe -Wl,-subsystem,console -mthreads -o debug\test01.exe debug/cuda/vectoradd_cuda.o debug/obj/main.o "-LC:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.1\lib\x64" -lcuda -lcudart -lcudadevrt -LC:\Qt\Qt5.10.0\5.10.0\mingw53_32\lib C:\Qt\Qt5.10.0\5.10.0\mingw53_32\lib\libQt5Cored.a, ...) failed.
make (e=2): Le fichier spécifié est introuvable.

mingw32-make[1]: *** [debug\test01.exe] Error 2
Makefile:36: recipe for target 'debug' failed
mingw32-make: *** [debug] Error 2
19:00:05: Le processus "C:\Qt\Qt5.10.0\Tools\mingw530_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" s'est terminé avec le code 2.
Erreur lors de la compilation/déploiement du projet test01 (kit : Desktop Qt 5.10.0 MinGW 32bit)
When executing step "Make"
19:00:05: Temps écoulé : 00:02.
```

The .pro file:
    QT -= gui

```
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any feature of Qt which as been marked deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# Source files
SOURCES += main.cpp

# This makes the .cu files appear in your project
# OTHER_FILES +=  vectoradd.cu

# CUDA settings <-- may change depending on your system
CUDA_SOURCES += vectoradd.cu
CUDA_DIR = "C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v9.1"            # Path to cuda toolkit install
SYSTEM_NAME = x64
NVCC_OPTIONS = --use_fast_math -dlink

# include paths
INCLUDEPATH += $$CUDA_DIR\include

# library directories
QMAKE_LIBDIR += $$CUDA_DIR/lib/$$SYSTEM_NAME \

# Add the necessary libraries
LIBS += -lcuda -lcudart 

QMAKE_LINK = mingw32_make.exe

# The following makes sure all path names (which often include spaces) are put between quotation marks
CUDA_INC = $$join(INCLUDEPATH,'" -I"','-I"','"')

# Configuration of the Cuda compiler
CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
    # Debug mode
    DESTDIR = debug
    OBJECTS_DIR = debug/obj
    CUDA_OBJECTS_DIR = debug/cuda

    cuda_d.input = CUDA_SOURCES
    cuda_d.output = $$CUDA_OBJECTS_DIR/${QMAKE_FILE_BASE}_cuda.o
    cuda_d.commands = $$CUDA_DIR/bin/nvcc.exe -D_DEBUG $$NVCC_OPTIONS $$CUDA_INC $$LIBS -c -o ${QMAKE_FILE_OUT} ${QMAKE_FILE_NAME}
    cuda_d.dependency_type = TYPE_C
    QMAKE_EXTRA_COMPILERS += cuda_d
}
else {
    # Release mode
    DESTDIR = release
    OBJECTS_DIR = release/obj
    CUDA_OBJECTS_DIR = release/cuda

    cuda.input = CUDA_SOURCES
    cuda.output = $$CUDA_OBJECTS_DIR/${QMAKE_FILE_BASE}_cuda.o
    cuda.commands = $$CUDA_DIR/bin/nvcc.exe $$NVCC_OPTIONS $$CUDA_INC $$LIBS -c -o ${QMAKE_FILE_OUT} ${QMAKE_FILE_NAME}
    cuda.dependency_type = TYPE_C
    QMAKE_EXTRA_COMPILERS += cuda
}
```

The main.cpp file:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

#include <cuda.h>

typedef std::chrono::high_resolution_clock timer;
typedef std::chrono::duration<float, std::ratio<1, 1000> > chrono;

void add_wrapper(int n, float *x, float *y);

int main()
{
    std::chrono::time_point<timer> start = timer::now();

    int N = 1<<20;

    float *x = new float[N];
    float *y = new float[N];

    for(int i=0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        x[i] = 1.0f;
        y[i] = 2.0f;
    }

    add_wrapper(N, x, y);

    float maxError = 0.0f;
    for(int i=0; i < N; ++i)
        maxError = fmax(maxError, fabs(y[i] - 3.0f));

    std::cout << "Max error: " << maxError << " obtained in ";
    std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<chrono>(timer::now() - start).count() << " ms \n";

    delete[] x;
    delete[] y;

    return 0;
}
```

And the vectoradd.cu file:

```
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>

__global__
void addVectors(int n, float *x, float *y)
{
    for(int i=0; i < n; ++i)
        y[i] = x[i] + y[i];
}

void add_wrapper(int n, float *x, float *y)
{
    float *d_x = new float[n];
    float *d_y = new float[n];

    cudaMallocManaged(&x, sizeof(float));
    cudaMallocManaged(&y, sizeof(float));

    cudaMemcpy(d_x, x, sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_y, y, sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    addVectors<<<1, 1>>>(n, d_x, d_y);

    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    cudaMemcpy(x, d_x, sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaMemcpy(y, d_y, sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    cudaFree(d_x);
    cudaFree(d_y);
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: mingw isn't a supported compiler for CUDA, on any platform

Comment: And 32 bit toolchain support was deprecated and removed from CUDA some time ago, so there are at least two reasons why this can't work

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll switch to msvc then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do is unsupported.

As per the [documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-microsoft-windows/index.html), the only supported toolchain on Windows platforms is Visual Studio. You may well be able to use QT Creator and Qmake to build projects, but you must use the Microsoft toolchain to compile and link code. MinGW and gcc are unsupported. Note also that 32 bit toolchains are also unsupported in recent versions of CUDA. You can cross compile to a 32 bit target using the toolchain, but native 32 bit toolchain support on Windows was dropped several years ago.